# Concurrent update of two elements in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

This code produces two elements where in slow motion I write the values of the variable of a for loop. The problem is that I thought the two writing operations would happen concurrently and not one after the other, as it currently happens. How can I get the two elements to update concurrently?

my **index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/shiny.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/> 
        <style>
            .shiny-text-output { border: 1px solid green; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <pre id="results2" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
        <pre id="results4" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ("myCallbackHandler",
            function (value) {
                document.getElementById ("results2").innerHTML = value;
            }
        );

        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ("myOtherCallbackHandler",
            function (value) {
                document.getElementById ("results4").innerHTML = value;
            }
        );
    </script>
</html>
```

my **server.R**

```
shinyServer (function (input, output, session)
{
    observe ({
        for (i in 1:3)
        {
            session$sendCustomMessage (type="myCallbackHandler", i);
            Sys.sleep (2);
        }
    });

    observe ({
        for (i in 1:4)
        {
            session$sendCustomMessage (type="myOtherCallbackHandler", i);
            Sys.sleep (1);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You'd have update them at the same time in the same observer.

Comment: I merged the code under one `observe` call but I get the same thing back.

Comment: the loops have to be merged, too, of course.

Comment: but the loops do different things.

Comment: well, you should be able to merge them, considering that they are both fundamentally just iterating over something.

Comment: this is only a minimal working example. actual code is 10s of lines.

Comment: this is the only way to accomplish what you're trying to do without using some parallelization library, which I'm not sure would work.